# how to pause time when browser tab changes or minimizes

Tags: timer, pause

pls share how to pause time when browser tab changes or minimizes and resume when tab is active.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id= "startButtons">
          <button  style="width:20px; height:20px; background-color:red; border:1px solid black; cursor:hand;" id= "yogaStart">T</button>
        </div>
        <div id= "countdown"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("yogaStart").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var timeleft = 10;

    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1(){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Wait"+"&nbsp"+timeleft+"&nbsp"+"Seconds";


    timeleft -= 1;
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time is up!"
    }
    }, 1000);

    console.log(countdown);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

how to pause time when browser tab changes or minimizes and resume when tab is active